# Adjusting for confounders when the investigated exposures are gene mutations

Tags: multiple-regression, causality, confounding, dag

I'm delving into causality and directed acyclic graph for choosing the right covariate structure for multivariable regression analysis.

Reading Pearl work, I understood that one should adjust only for variables which have a causal relation with (cause a change in observed data frequency) both exposures and outcomes.

I was wondering how, given this assumption, one should behave when studying the effect of a genetic variant on an outcome. Should one consider other clinical variables as confounders? Since, as it is obvious, any clinical variable will be at most consequence and never a cause of a genetic variant, could one just use univariate analysis to asses the effect of the mutated gene on the outcome?

[image]

Second question, what if you want to study the effects of a number of genes mutations on the outcome? Should the various gene be considered as covariates or they should be analyzed independently?

Thanks

Comment: If the DAG you provided holds, then the causal effect of Exp on the outcome is identified, use e.g. the back-door theorem (that is, if the DAG is correct). I don't understand your second paragraph, though. For starters, how does one know what's causally related before doing the analysis?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. My hypothesis is that a congenital gene mutation, by it's nature, can only (but not necessarily) be the cause and never be caused by any other variable of a patient. So I'm asking if confounding adjustment is ever needed for this kind of exposures.

Comment: Similarly, for the second question, every gene mutation (apart from specific cases regarding DNA management related genes) is independent one from another. So if my hypothesis olds, you would never need to adjust the effect of a mutation for the effect of the others, since there should not be any causal association among them.

Comment: If you are sure that gene mutation is never caused by another patient-level variable, you're free to go without adjustment, which follows directly from the back-door criterion. But gene mutations might be inherited, and if relatives had the same mutation and suffered from the same outcomes, this might confound the relationship between a patient's mutation and his outcome?

Comment: Right! As I said I'm trying to consider only the general most common case, assuming that observations (that is, patients) are independent. I am a bit troubled because in the analysis I'm conducting, there are some variables that even if not clearly associated with the primary exposure (gene mutation in this case), if added to the multivariable model do change the significancy of the primary variable.

Comment: @Bakaburg That might be a small-sample issue due to variability in the data, or due to asymptotically wrong conditioning on variables that violate the back-door criterion, e.g. a descendant of the treatment (other variable 1 in your graph). To avoid the latter, you have to make substantive causal arguments. The former is a statistical issue that depends on the concrete data.

Comment: Understood your answer, thanks! It would be great to find a paper that justify the hypothesis that with genes mutation adjusting for patient level variables is not needed. If you do that, or justify some other way your comment I'll accept your answer!